# PrintOut de Microsoft.Office.Interop.word.dll só realiza impressão de documento com 1 página

Tags: c#, microsoft-word, interoperabilidade

Bom dia pessoal. Estou usanso a lib `Microsof.Office.Interop.Word.dll` para realizar a impressão de um documento do word.
Quando o documento tem apenas uma página, a impressão funciona normalmente.
O problema é quando tem mais de uma página, ele não funciona. Não apresenta erro nem nada, apenas não sai na impressora.
Estou usando esses parametros:

```
word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(
                   true,
                   false, 
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintAllDocument,
                   Item: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutItem.wdPrintDocumentContent,
                   Copies: "1", 
                   //Pages: "1,2",
                   PageType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdPrintOutPages.wdPrintAllPages,
                   PrintToFile: false, 
                   Collate: true,
                   ManualDuplexPrint: false);
```

Já coloquei Pages: "1,2", Pages: "1-2" e nada,
Já fiz sem passar os argumentos também, e nada

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.
O problema era que eu estava fechando o documento logo depois do PrintOut
então alterei o codigo para esperar o términdo da impressão e só depois fechar o documento:

```
 Log.LoggerAPI.LogInfo("Aguarando término da impressão");
                while (word.BackgroundPrintingStatus == 1) { }



                if (word.BackgroundPrintingStatus == 0)
                {
                    Log.LoggerAPI.LogInfo("Fechando documento sem salvar as alterações");
                    doc.Close(SaveChanges: false);

                    doc = null;
                    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application)word).Quit(SaveChanges: false);
                    word = null;
                }
```